# How i get a dynamic url in my websocket tornado?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, tornado

How do I get the dynamic url passed by js in my websocket, do I need it to pass by parameter to the pc.connect() class that today does not receive anything but in the future will it?

webosocket:

```
class MyWebSocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def allow_draft76(self):
        # for iOS 5.0 Safari
        return True

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.application.pc.add_event_listener(self)
        print ("WebSocket opened")

    def on_close(self):
        print ("WebSocket closed")
        self.application.pc.remove_event_listener(self)

def main():
    parse_command_line()
    aplication = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'.*', MyWebSocketHandler)
    ])
    pc = PikaClient(io_loop)
    aplication.pc = pc
    aplication.pc.connect()
    aplication.listen(8081)
    io_loop.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

html:

```
const websocket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.99.100:8081/${this.$route.params.uri}')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement multiple URL parameters in a Tornado route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744454/how-can-i-implement-multiple-url-parameters-in-a-tornado-route)

Comment: Is there no way to get the path info in the main function? in the topic he talks about picking up inside the handler class

Answer (score 0):

In the application, define the route like this:

```
(r'/(.*)', MyWebSocketHandler),
```

The parentheses define a *capturing group* which will be passed to `open()` as `args[0]`.

Also note that the `allow_draft76` method was removed in Tornado 4.0, so there is no longer any reason to include this method in your handler.

Comment: but how i put the args[0] inside of my class PikaClient without a global var? I need to construct my mq with this parameter.

Comment: Then you need to create your PikaClient in `MyWebSocketHandler.open` instead of `main`.